# Writing to variable from MySQL databases in bash script

Tags: mysql, database, bash, variables

I have a problem with writing in the variable from table in MySQL database.

```
DB="--user=$OSD_USERNAME \
    --password=$OSD_PASSWORD \ 
    --database=$OSD_DB -N";
mysql --user="$user" \
      --password="$password" \
      --database="$database" \
      --execute="DROP DATABASE $user; CREATE DATABASE $database;"

id_customer = $(echo "SELECT id FROM customers WHERE customers.customer='John'"| mysql $DB)
```

My problem is that id_customer is still empty.
When I connect to mysql databases and put there this:

```
SELECT id FROM customers WHERE customers.customer='John'
```

then it give me table like this

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 | 
+----+
```

Comment: It won't put on formatting if you call it with a piped in script. Try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only empty, no errors? Try remove spaces between variable name and $